# How to get values without key from JSON object in JavaScript(HTML)

Tags: javascript, json

```html
                 [17/02/2020]      [18/02/2020]    [19/02/2020]
itemseq    1 Allocated        2             6              7
itemname   2 Out Of Order     0             0              0
```

```js
success: function (result) {
                    debugger;
                    var Item1 = JSON.parse(result.Item1)
                  
                    if (Item1.length == 0) {
                        $('<tr><td colspan="4">No Record Found</td></tr>').appendTo($('#Tablev'));
                    }
                    $('#Tablev tr:not(:first)').empty();

                        $('<tr>' +
                            '<th ' + item.itemseq+ '</th>' +
                            '<th>' + item.itemname + '</th>' +
                            (need to get the Date and date values like we got the above 2 things)


                            '</tr>').appendTo($('#Tablev'));
                    });
```

I'm trying to add  **key values for eg-(dates "16/02/2020"): and the value it contains(0)** and show them on a grid, I managed to get the `itemseq` and `itemname` but I have no idea how to get the other two key values.**The dates and value are received from mssql on user input date ranges.**

JSON string in JavaScript I receive is (the json string keeps ongoing on this is half of the code)

```
[
  {
    "itemseq": 1,
    "itemname": "Allocated",
    "17/02/2020": 2,
    "18/02/2020": 6,
    "19/02/2020": 7,
    "20/02/2020": 3,
    "21/02/2020": 7,
    "22/02/2020": 6,
    "23/02/2020": 2,
    "24/02/2020": 5
  },
  {
    "itemseq": 2,
    "itemname": "Out Of Order",
    "17/02/2020": 0,
    "18/02/2020": 0,
    "19/02/2020": 0,
    "20/02/2020": 0,
    "21/02/2020": 0,
    "22/02/2020": 0,
    "23/02/2020": 0,
    "24/02/2020": 0
  },
  {
    "itemseq": 3,
    "itemname": "Daily Occupancy %",
    "17/02/2020": 28.57,
    "18/02/2020": 85.71,
    "19/02/2020": 100,
    "20/02/2020": 42.85,
    "21/02/2020": 100,
    "22/02/2020": 85.71,
    "23/02/2020": 28.57,
    "24/02/2020": 71.42
  }
]
```

How could i take the dates and the values of the dates it contains 
**"(date)18/02/2020": (value)85.71,**

**when we are using the string we can break the string and get the values like
(item.itemseq item.itemname) and i want to know how could i get the values of dates and the date values because these data are passed to a grid and gonna be used there..

eg- 
columns- the dates [18/02/2020] [19/02/2020]
and the rows wise we have the [Allocated][Out Of Order] for the specific date it should contains the value that date has [85.71][100]**

Comment: Please, can you add the portion of the code that intends to use this data to power the grid? This would make it easy to understand the data transformation that needs to take place.

Comment: I just added the html and the script

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const json = [{"itemseq":1,"itemname":"Allocated","17/02/2020":2.0000,"18/02/2020":6.0000,"19/02/2020":7.0000,"20/02/2020":3.0000,"21/02/2020":7.0000,"22/02/2020":6.0000,"23/02/2020":2.0000,"24/02/2020":5.0000},{"itemseq":2,"itemname":"Out Of Order","17/02/2020":0.0000,"18/02/2020":0.0000,"19/02/2020":0.0000,"20/02/2020":0.0000,"21/02/2020":0.0000,"22/02/2020":0.0000,"23/02/2020":0.0000,"24/02/2020":0.0000},{"itemseq":3,"itemname":"Daily Occupancy %","17/02/2020":28.5700,"18/02/2020":85.7100,"19/02/2020":100.0000,"20/02/2020":42.8500,"21/02/2020":100.0000,"22/02/2020":85.7100,"23/02/2020":28.5700,"24/02/2020":71.4200}]

json.map((item) => {
 console.log(item["21/02/2020"])
})
```

It will return:

```
7
0
100
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean add a value to each item you can try this

```js
let data = [
    {"itemseq":1,"itemname":"Allocated","17/02/2020":2.0000,"18/02/2020":6.0000,"19/02/2020":7.0000,"20/02/2020":3.0000,"21/02/2020":7.0000,"22/02/2020":6.0000,"23/02/2020":2.0000,"24/02/2020":5.0000},
    {"itemseq":2,"itemname":"Out Of Order","17/02/2020":0.0000,"18/02/2020":0.0000,"19/02/2020":0.0000,"20/02/2020":0.0000,"21/02/2020":0.0000,"22/02/2020":0.0000,"23/02/2020":0.0000,"24/02/2020":0.0000},
    {"itemseq":3,"itemname":"Daily Occupancy %","17/02/2020":28.5700,"18/02/2020":85.7100,"19/02/2020":100.0000,"20/02/2020":42.8500,"21/02/2020":100.0000,"22/02/2020":85.7100,"23/02/2020":28.5700,"24/02/2020":71.4200}
];

let copy = [];
data.forEach((item) => {
    item["16/02/2020"] = 0;
    copy.push(item);
});
console.log(copy);
```

"16/02/2020" index is added with value : 0 to each item